# Plot residuals vs. predictor variable in the R programming language

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I have the SLR model in R

```
model<-lm(Y~X,data)
```

I need to make a plot both of Residuals vs. Yhat and Residuals vs. predictor. Yes, I know that they provide the same information and yes, I need to make both anyway.

I know I can get residual vs. Yhat from `plot(model)`, but I cannot find a way to get the predictor version.

Can someone tell me how to extract the full (non-rounded) values of b0 and b1 from an lm model object? Then I could calculate the residuals myself.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You can get the coefficients with `coef(model)` but you can get the fitted values with `fitted(model)` and the residuals `resid(model)`. That should give you you what you need.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, coef(model) and resid(model) were what I needed. To your comments about reproducible examples, I think I included all the code I knew how to write. Once I had the model object, I was stuck from there, and that's the one line of code I wrote. If you'd like to put a formal answer on this post, I'd be happy to accept it.